# hostfxr.dll missing on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: .net, linux, ubuntu, .net-core

When I try to run wine `program.exe` on **linux (ubuntu 22.04)** I get an error

> A fatal error occurred. The required library hostfxr.dll could not be
> found...

Currently I have two runtimes installed `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.9` and `Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.9`. I tried installing `sdk - 7.0.109` but it did not help. They are installed in /usr/lib/dotnet directory